# GWT: include undefined class parameter on function

Tags: java, function, gwt, parameters

I have this function in my GWT project:

```
private InputElement getInputElement(int rowIndex, int columnIndex, 
CellTable<MyClassA> cellTable) {
        InputElement input = null;
        if (isColumnEditable(columnIndex)) {
            input = (InputElement) cellTable.getRowElement(rowIndex).getCells().getItem(columnIndex).getFirstChild().getFirstChild();
        }  
        return input;
    }
```

If would like to re-use this function when the last parameter is `CellTable<MyClassB>`, because the rest of the code is exactly the same. How can I do that?

Comment: are MyClassA and MyClassB are related??

Comment: Nope. But for this function should be the same. As you can see, we are not working with MyClass, just with the cellTable functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write the following code -

> `public interface MyClassInterface 
>      {
>           ...
>      }`

`public class MyClassA implements MyClassInterface
   {
        ...
   }`

`public class MyClassB implements MyClassInterface 
   {
        ...
   }`

```
private <T extends MyClassInterface> InputElement getInputElement(int rowIndex, int columnIndex, CellTable<T> cellTable)                    
{             
    InputElement input = null;              
    if (isColumnEditable(columnIndex))  
    {  
        input = (InputElement)  cellTable.getRowElement(rowIndex).getCells().getItem(columnIndex).getFirstChild().getFirstChild();  
    }  
    return input;
```

}

Answer (score 1):

You need to make a interface MyClassInterface and implement it in both classes.

```
public interface MyClassInterface {

}

public class MyClassA implements MyClassInterface {
   ...
}
public class MyClassB implements MyClassInterface {
   ...
}
private InputElement getInputElement(int rowIndex, int columnIndex, 
CellTable<? extends MyClassInterface> cellTable) {
        InputElement input = null;
        if (isColumnEditable(columnIndex)) {
            input = (InputElement) cellTable.getRowElement(rowIndex).getCells().getItem(columnIndex).getFirstChild().getFirstChild();
        }  
        return input;
    }
```

Comment: The method getInputElement(int, int, CellTable<CellTablePresenter.MyClassInterface>) in the type CellTablePresenter is not applicable for the arguments (int, int, CellTable<MyClassA>)

Comment: Thanks. Just did what you said. Empty interface and add the "implements MyClassInterface" on both MyClassA and MyClassB. However I get the error above. And a similar one for MyClassB.

Comment: You have to make the interface and the classes in separate files.

Comment: In the method sig, `cellTable` probably needs to be of type `CellTable<? extends MyClassInterface>` or the like.